# How to efficiently retrieve data given the following model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

It may be something that has already been asked but I was not able to find it. I have a model that contains the following three columns: [“id”, “category”, “name”] and I would like to organize my page like this:

Header (list of all the categories, link to a table with all the names for that category and count of names under that category)

- Category 1: 5 names
- Category 2: 7 names
- Category 3: 4 names

Content (one table per category listing all the names under that category)

- Table “category 1”: “name1”, “…” name5”
- Table “category 2”: “name1”, “…” name7”
- Table “category 3”: “name1”, “…” name4”

To achieve this I basically need a map of categories to a collection of names, nothing too fancy but I would like to know what the best practice would be. Getting all the categories first and then running one query for each of them to get the names does not seem to be efficient. What I would do in java is get everything in a result set, iterates over it and build the map I mentioned. Not sure about how to achieve this in rails.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
h = {}                                                                       
MyModel.all.sort_by(&:category).each do |m|                                                      
  h[m.category] ||= []                                                       
  h[m.category] << m.name                                                    
end                                                                          

h.each do |category, names|                                                  
  puts "#{category}: #{names.count} names"                                   
end                                                                          

h.each do |category, names|                                                  
  puts "#{category}: #{names.sort * ', '}"                                        
end
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why you sorted the collection of model though?

Comment: In Ruby >= 1.9, hashes preserve insertion order, so the category names should print in order as in your example: